# Dynamics CRM access check flow

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to find out how Microsoft has built access check flow in Dynamics CRM. What is the order of checks(security role, team, sharing)? The reason is that I came to a project where they created logic to share all records of one entity with a team, based on some criteria. All users are members of this team. Now we have a lot of records in POA table regarding this entity and one of my queries times out if it is not ran by user with admin permissions.

I wonder if it would be more efficient if this team was owner of a record instead of a record being shared with the team? Will CRM check user's membership in the team before running through POA table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I'm assuming the following:

1. All records of some entity, call it new_entity, are shared to a specific team, call it TeamA.
2. All users are a member of TeamA.

They could eliminate the sharing and team membership altogether by giving all users the desired permission to the entity type in question.

It will certainly be more efficient to have everyone be a member of the team than it would be to share with the team, since it will mostly eliminate the POA table. That said, how big is the POA table? POA used to be an issue but at this point, if they are up-to-date on Rollups, most POA issues are a result of bad queries, missing indexes, or poor disk/memory configuration on the SQL server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for so late response. POA table contains near 1500000 records related to this new_entity. Majority of new_entity records is shared to that team, others are not shared and should not be available to all users. Do you recommend assigning all these records to the team instead of sharing? Do I have to remove sharing (assume it can be done via code)? How do I clean POA after that?

Comment: 1.5M records in POA should not be an issue. I think you need to look at the performance of your SQL Server (especially the indexing strategy.) What rollup are you on? Can you share the query that is poorly performing?

Comment: I don't have a specific query to share, but we do have performance problems with sql server which is on virtual machine with disks being a part of SAN... But I was just wondering if members of a team will experience better performance if the record was assigned to their team (set team as the owner) instead of being shared with the same team? Would CRM perform a more lightweight query to determine if user has permissions?

Comment: How many teams would a user be a member of? Max, min, and average. I'm working on a similar problem and if team membership grows beyond 2000 or 5000 you start experiencing performance issues. They are reportedly solved in rollup 16 but we are still testing.

Comment: No, it is not more than 10 teams. So I think it would not make a big difference. But today our DB admin discovered strange behaviour. If a user who is not in business unit on top searches contacts (in a lookup view for example), CRM gets ALL the contacts from database and matches with POA table. The user has Org. level read access on contacts. With user in top BU and same security roles, POA is not queried and just a few contacts were returned. What could be the reason for this?